# Microsoft Graph API - $filter email address by domain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As Title, I try to filter my email by domain. But got a error message "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter". How can I do?

API query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=endswith(from/emailAddress/address,'@xxx.com')
```

Response:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
    "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2023-02-03T08:59:37",
        "request-id": "b3a28220-91d1-40b5-a34a-10cc73069951",
        "client-request-id": "74043780-6e6b-dc63-5434-0ac03412b3ca"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endsWith` operator is not supported for filtering messages by `from/emailAddress/address`.

As a workaround you can use `contains`. It will have the same affect for email address as using `endsWith` if you will filter by `@domain`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(from/emailAddress/address,'@xxx.com')
```